# How to refresh a div in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have implemented paging in my project.But div tag is not getting refresh so I am get improper result.for that I tried reload() function of the jquery.

Comment: Explain better your problem, and post your code here. Do you have an ajax to get the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the content of your div tag element, you need to use the html() or text() function. The html() function is to set a html code into your div and the text() is to set a text into the div.

See documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/html/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

An example:

```
$('#mydiv').html('Content');
```

If you will implement a paging without refresh the page, you will need to make an ajax request to get the content of your div and change it.

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'paging.php?page=2',
    success: function (data) {
        $('mydiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

Another option is to use the load function:

```
$('#mydiv').load('paging.php?page=2');
```

Documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.its working but it is showing some numerical data on div.

Answer (score 0):

Use location.reload():

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("#particularDiv").load(location.href+" #particularDiv>*","");
```